# Disable security for Springboot actuator endpoint /env

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

**Requirement :**

I have a small springboot 2 , config-server project with just one java file (SpringBootApplication). My requirement is that actuator endpoint /actuator/env alone should be not challenged with spring security.

**What I am able to do:**

I am able to bypass security for /actuator/health by using `http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/actuator/health").permitAll()` - [WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter] , so that opening that link will not ask credentials.

**What I'd like to do:**

But if I do the same for /env (`.antMatchers("/actuator/env").permitAll()`) , it still shows the default spring security credentials page. Please help.

**Actuators Config in application.yml** 
`management:
      endpoints:
        web:
          base-path: /actuator
          exposure:
            include: health,env
      endpoint:
        health:
          show-details: always`

**Security Config:**

```
`@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfigurer extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/actuator/env").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/actuator/env/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/actuator/health").permitAll();
        super.configure(http);
    }
}`
```

Answer (score 2):

**/actuator/env** endpoint is disabled by default. You need to include it in your application.properties:

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=env
```

Also this:

```
http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/actuator/**").permitAll();
```

will you allow anything under /actuator path

Comment: Ok I'll update the full security config in few mins. /env is working after successful authentication without any erroe. Also since I'm running in my local, i have the console with me. There are no errors thrown.

Comment: You are not using antMatchers("/actuator/**") the way I suggested, however your Security Config should work. The error must be somewhere else